# C# WebApi - Sending long text in HTTPRequest not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am working on a WebApp (Razor Pages) that work also as API Gateway. The WebApp get some data from another project (part of the same solution) that is a WebAPI.
The problem is that when I do an HTTPRequest to the WebAPI, if the request is not too long, the WebAPI will process it, but when I try to send a longer request (long in characters) it will reject it and send back a 404.

The WebApp is a basic CMS. So the app will provide to the user, the creation of Web pages. I am using a restful request model so a request will look like this:

```cs
string baseURL = @"https://localhost:5001";

public async Task<string> CreatePageAsync(string pageTitle, string pageBody, int? pageOrder, string userID)
{
      if (pageTitle != null && pageBody != null && pageOrder != null && userID != null)
      {
           string fullURL = baseURL + $"/api/pages/create/page/title/{pageTitle}/body/{pageBody}/order/{pageOrder}/user/{userID}";

           var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, fullURL);
           HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

           if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
                return "error";
           }
       }

       return "ok";
}
```

As you can imagine, the "pageBody" property is the one responsible for the length of the request. So, when I test the WebAPI with short words, it works just fine, but if I copy an article from the internet (Just text) and use it as the body (simulating the user's content), if it is a long one, it will return a 404.

On the other end, the WebAPI looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost("Create/page/title/{pageTitle}/body/{pageBody}/order/{pageOrder}/user/{userID}")]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<string> CreatePage(string pageTitle, string pageBody, int pageOrder, string userID) //[Bind("pageName,pageHead,pageBody,userID")]
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                WebPage newPage = new WebPage()
                {
                    PageID = _globalServices.GuidFromString(_globalServices.GetSeed()),
                    PageDateCreated = now,
                    PageDateUpdated = now,
                    PageOrder = pageOrder,
                    PageTitle = pageTitle,
                    PageBody = pageBody,
                    UserID = userID
                };

                try
                {
                    await _pagesDBContext.Pages.AddAsync(newPage);
                    await _pagesDBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string message = "ERROR: Could not save to the database.\n";
                    return message + e.Message;
                }

                return "Page saved";
            }

            return "ERROR: Model invalid";
        }
```

I am sending the request as simple text. I don't know if there is a better way.

Any ideas?

Comment: How long is long?

Comment: For example, I am testing a body with exactly 4024 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment but it looks like the maximum characters you can send in a GET request is 2,048.

Comment: Thanks Frawsky!
I think I found two different problems.
The first one were the characters. I was using a part of a text I copied from an IT article and it contained characters like "/,( )," In particular the upper slash (I believe that is how this "/" character is called) which was confusing and taken as a divisor in the query itself. So I removed those -and some other special characters- and it worked!
The second was the length. It will accept a body of 4000 chars but not one with 5500 chars.
So now I need some ideas on how to deal with special characters and length. Ideas?

Comment: I am so sorry I am just now seeing this. I hope you got it resolved!

Comment: I will never forgive you Frawsty... haha now seriously, I left it on the side so I would not block myself (which is an issue when not resolving immediately). I need to present this tomorrow so I figured WTH I will make it work first and then, polish it.. So don't go too far, I might need some backup here!

Comment: Sure thing! I'm not an expert by any means BUT two heads are always better than one!